# Can I overlap the WebView with an ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

What I want to create should look like this :

[image]

I want it like this because I want the button to cover a part of the content of the webview making it unreachable for the user.

Comment: Ignore the fact that in the example the imagebutton is a bit lower than the webview it can be on it as long as it is overlapping the bottom of the webview

Comment: What are you trying to hide?

Comment: I had the idea to cover the youtube mediaplayer minimize/fullscreen button and replace it with my own but I'm still going through options as for another thing I want to use this to cover the entire webview with a black alpha image and place a new webview above it displaying the image in it's full size. Still experimenting with the things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `FrameLayout` as follows...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do.for that purpose you have to use relative layout.first you have add webview,then add image button and set gravity bottom to image button.i think this can help you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />
        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```