# How to cover a WebView with a semi-transparent covering layer that prevents the WebView from being touched?

Tags: android, xml, webview, overlap

I'm trying to have a webpage load but I want the user to see the page loading but be unable to interact with it until the page loads.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/mainWebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#40606060"
    />
```

I just thought I'd put a semi-transparent, gray layer over it which I would hide when the page has loaded. I think what I need is two views inside some sort of container. This post ([Can I overlap the `WebView` with an `ImageButton`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227904/can-i-overlap-the-webview-with-an-imagebutton)) has a similar question but when I use a `WebView` I can still interact it by scrolling.So I've been using a `WebView` and a `LinearLayout` (i've tried an `ImageView` as well) inside a `FrameLayout` (I've tried a `GridLayout` as well).

In both cases, I can cover the `WebView` just like I want but I can still interact with the `Webview` by scrolling with my finger and I don't want that. In HTML I would just put one DIV on top of another and it would accomplish this but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent with Android.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add id to ur linear layout, wrap web view and linear layout(cover) in relative layout (make ur linear cover on top(above) add click listener to ur cover and web view will not touched cos ur cover listen for click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `LinearLayout` as clickeable = "true"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#40606060"
    android:clickeable="true"
    />
```

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you! One line!

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement `WebViewClient` and extend `onPageFinished()` as follows:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

you can show progress dialogue when `WebView` start load the page and dismiss `ProgressBar` `onPageFinished()` Method.

Tell me if you have still any query...